# How to secure an aging PC from the switch/router side?

Tags: cisco, networking

I have an aging Windows XP PC whose purpose is to feed code to a manufacturing machine via a RS-232 connection using machine-specific software.  The PC needs to retrieve its code from a network file share.  This PC came with the manufacturing machine (purchased used), and I do not have / cannot obtain its administrator password.  Furthermore, the PC has automatic updates disabled and its firewall disabled and these cannot be turned on without admin access.  I am concerned about the security risk of having an un-updated / un-firewalled PC on my network.

Can I somehow secure this machine through settings on our Cisco managed switch (SG300) in order to limit it to its one and only network related task - which is to connect to a network file share?  The machine does not need internet access.  It only needs access to a single network file share.  Is there a way this can be done?

Here is more detailed info about our network configuration:

- The managed switch is a Cisco SG300.  It is handling all Layer 3 switching.
- The file server is connected to the Cisco SG300 switch.
- The router is a Ubiquiti Edgerouter X, however I believe this is out of the picture because the Cisco switch is doing all internal switching and handling Vlans.
- The aging PC is connected to the network via Wifi.
- The aging PC does not have a Wifi card, so it is connecting to Wifi via a wired-ethernet to wifi adapter (IOGear GWU627W6).
- The wireless access point is a Ubiquiti Unifi AP-LR, which is connected to the Cisco SG300 switch.

Comment: We need more information. At least a good description of the network, the network device models, and the network device configurations. Refer to the [Network Engineering Question Checklist](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/292/8499) for guidance, then edit your question.

Comment: Basically the only thing you could do on the switch is VLAN segmentation. With this, you would have a seperate logical broadcast domain but no chance to control the traffic like a firewall does. Furthermore you would need something for routing. As Ron already wrote we need some more details. If you have a firewall in your network, a simple solution could be to do basic stateful packet inspection between your WinXP PC (which is in a seperate VLAN) and the file server.

Comment: Hello PMetal and welcome to Network Engineering.  What manufacturer and model of switch is Aging PC plugged into?  Is server on same switch?

Comment: We still need the network device configurations. It sounds like you need a separate SSID and VLAN for the PC (much like a guest SSID and VLAN), which you can then use ACLs to restrict access, but we cannot help unless you give us enough information.

Comment: Thank you for your input - I have updated the original post with additional network details.  I like the idea to use a separate VLAN to separate it.  I could certainly use a separate SSID for this machine as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Consider adding MAC based access-control lists to your switch.  This will make it so that Aging PC can only send and receive frames to and from the server
- Consider IP address and port ACLs, so it can only do file-share related tasks even with this server
- Consider changing Aging PC to wired: then only frames have to go through the switch to the PC
- Consider putting Aging PC's wifi in a SSID of its own, if you can't make it wired
- Consider direct wire from PC to second NIC on server, with otherwise unrouted IP address